# Reading SMS not working

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, smsmanager

I have written below method to read the incoming sms text. This code is working perfectly in Android 4.04 when the default SMS client is the native SMS client, but when the SMS client is Hangout the method does not work.

The same method works in Android 5 with Hangout as the SMS client, the problem is only in Android 4.04 with Hangout as SMS client. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

```
static boolean readSMS(Intent intent, int code) {
    try {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                if (message.contains(String.valueOf(code)))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The method is invoked from the java code within a BroadCastReceiver.

```
     receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                     if (readSMS(intent, code)) {
                    ------------------
                    }
                }
```

The `BroadCastReceiver` is invoked as:

```
   context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incoming SMS is a `Broadcast transmission` which you can register a `receiver` to listen to it and respond according to your logic. You can register multiple receivers to the SMS broadcast, and they will all get the SMS, one by one, by a certain order.
How can we know the order? Each receiver has a `priority`, and the OS dispatches the SMS from the higher priority receiver to the lower ones.
Upto `Android 4.4` (excluding), you could have use the `abortBroadcast();` statement, which would terminate the dispatching. Lets say that we have two apps - A and B with SMS receivers. If A has higher priority than B and A uses the abort statement, then app B wil never get the SMS. From `Android 4.4` and on, you can't abort SMS transmissions anymore.
From your question it looks like that when you use `Android 4.0.4` the Hangout client has a higher priority from your app, and it aborts the broadcast transmission, while the default client does not abort it (or has a lower priority). When you switch to Android 5, the Hangout cannot abort the SMS, so your app works as it should.
As to the priorities - the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) states that "*The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000.*".
You can add to your menifanifest the line

```
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
```

and hope that the Hangout's priority is lower.

Comment: The priority can be set much higher than that, up to and including the maximum values of Integer in Java. Also, you can just see what priority Hangouts has set for their receiver - it'll be in their manifest.

Comment: @TheoLassonder Is there any way checking the Hangouts manifest? I thought there is no way to do that

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ I've checked it, It is encrypted. But try to add the `priority` line to your manifest and check it with different values, you've nothing to lose.

Comment: @TDG it can't be encrypted because the system needs to read it. Also, you can programmatically list broadcast receivers of all apps, including their priority

Comment: @TheoLassonder - When I try to open a manifest file of downloaded app (not only Hangout) by extracting it from the APK, I get total Gibbrish. I'd like to know how can I open it. As for listing the receivers programatically - I wasn't aware for that, I'll google it, sounds interesting.

Comment: If you just treat the APK file as a zip file and extract the manifest, you get a compiled version of it. If you use a tool like http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool or https://github.com/lxdvs/apk2gold on the other hand, you get a nicely decoded version (along with lots of other things).

Comment: Regarding listing the receivers, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3168951/5109026